# Unix: using sed to replace a multi-line string

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
**I**(0,80041,11.03.2014-15:05:05:702+3600,32.IROUTED,317435,iptdm.dtag,0,153452069,241769,80041,1,#00000000000000000000000000000000){
A(**11.03.2014-15:04:59:492+3600**){a=**S9**,0102,,,,,,,,,,,{0,,;},,,,**1.2.3.4:5060**,,,,,,,,,;c=0,17;n=S9;p=255;s=sip;b=;e=0;x=,+498003301000,5.6.7.8,5060,,,,08003301000,sip.test.de,,,tag\=00E0F510024703F9633D883C7650,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,tag\=as0cd2768d,,+492214711,9.8.7.6,5060,,,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.2.3.4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;mlpp=;o=,,,0,15,0;}
C(**11.03.2014-15:05:02:237+3600**){a=S9,0102,,,,,,,D001,,,,{0,,;},,,,,,LNP_FILLED,RAD_OK,iiap492214711,,**iiai492214711**,,**ii498003301000**,;c=0,17;d=3465;n=S9;p=255;s=sip;x=,+498003301000,5.6.7.8,5060,,,,08003301000,sip.test.de,,,tag\=00E0F510024703F9633D883C7650,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,tag\=as0cd2768d,,+492214711,9.8.7.6,5060,,,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.2.3.4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;mlpp=;o=11,D001,,2,15,0;}
V(11.03.2014-15:05:05:702+3600){i=498003301000;k=teles;l=21f6f14f-a926-11e3-ad91-00e0f5100247,21f6f14f-a926-11e3-ad91-00e0f5100247,;m=toner,voip;q=9.8.7.6,g711alaw;qc=1,,0,g711alaw:g711ulaw:g723r63:g723ar63:g729r8:g729ar8:g729br8:g729abr8:clearmode,echo,auto,30,7,32,27,32,0,0,0,20,4294967295,rfc2833,96,red,force,both,,,,;qi=3,1.2.3.4,5060,9.8.7.6,5060,g711alaw;qs=2,132,172,21120,27520,4294967295,0,4294967295,0,0;tud=,D001,,,,;ivr=,;h323=,,,,0:0:0;sip=4b211f615c1edd2e19ee10296df8a177@sip.test.de;}
D(**11.03.2014-15:05:05:702+3600**){f=A,CAU_NCC,LOC_PUBL_NTWK_SERV_REM_USER,CAU_NCC,LOC_PUBL_NTWK_SERV_REM_USER;t=S,CAU_NCC,LOC_PUBL_NTWK_SERV_REM_USER,CAU_NCC,LOC_PUBL_NTWK_SERV_REM_USER;a=S9,0102,,,,,,,D001,,,,{0,,;},,,,,,LNP_FILLED,RAD_OK,iiap492214711,,iiai492214711,,ii498003301000,;x=,+498003301000,5.6.7.8,5060,,,,08003301000,sip.test.de,,,tag\=00E0F510024703F9633D883C7650,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,tag\=as0cd2768d,,+492214711,9.8.7.6,5060,,,,+492214711,sip.test.de,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.2.3.4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;o=11,D001,,2,15,0;}
E(11.03.2014-15:05:05:702+3600){g=;}
}
```

I want to grep some fields of every leg and put them into a csv file with sed or maybe awk:

```
I,11.03.2014-15:04:59:492+3600,S9,1.2.3.4:5060,11.03.2014-15:04:59:492+3600,iiai492214711,ii498003301000,11.03.2014-15:05:05:702+3600
```

My attempt:

```
sed 's/\([IO]\)(.*){
A(\(.*\)){a=\(.*\),.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,{.*,.*,.*;},.*,.*,.*,\(.*\),.*}
.*
C(\(.*\)){a=.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,{.*,.*,.*;},.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,\(.*\),.*,\(.*\),.*}
D(\(.*\)){.*}
.*
}/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8' file
```

How can I use sed to use this regex string about more than one line?

Comment: This seems to be an  `awk` job. Post example data and what you like to get out and we can have a look at it.

Comment: I would switch to a more powerful language, e.g. Perl.

Comment: Can you add a sample output?

Comment: I just add some example data to the post.

Comment: while sed or awk should be able to handle this, I agree with @choroba that you may be better suited trying out Perl or another language with powerful text processing tools (especially if you aren't familiar with sed or awk)

Comment: Is there a pattern of fields you want to grab? Getting random stuff from random lines is going to be tough in any language.

Comment: @jaypal: No, there is not. The fields itselfs cannot be matched by a regular expression. I need to parse the whole leg.

Comment: I want to do exactly what you want to do . but I lost  32.IROUTED document {virus and format problem :( }  . Do you have the Document of this version ? I want to know the place of Each fild .  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
sed -n '/[*][*]I.*{/,/^}/ {
   /^[*][*]I/ {s/^[^,]*,\([^,]*\),.*/I,\1/;h;}
   /^A/   {s/^[^=]=[*][*]\([^*]*\)[*][*]\.*[*][*]\([^*]*\)[*][*].*/\1,\2/;H;}
   /^B/   {#extract what you want on this line }
   ...
   /^}/ {g;s/\n/,/p;}
   }' YourFile
```

You extract on each portion of line (of the **I** group) the wanted info, separate with `,`, add it to the hold buffer and at the end, recall the buffer (of each line) and replace the new line with a `,` then prnt the result

Comment: Hm, I used the '**' in the example data only to illustrate, that this the value I want to grep. In addition, the "a=" in A(...){a=...} is fixed, like the "a=" in C(...){a=...}, too.

Comment: ** is a special char, i forget it, use [*][*] instead or \*\*. I change my reply code